# SVN ci -m command, what does text after the quotes mean?

Tags: svn

I came across this command earlier and was wondering what the text (the variable YYY) after the quotes mean when run in terminal:

> svn ci -m "XXX" YYY

ex:

> svn ci -m "ESM-100 file.py fix" file.py

like, what does the last "file.py" mean/do here? I don't see it as part of the commit message.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have to want to read [SVN Book](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html) somehow, at least in order to understand syntax of used commands
- In `svn ci -m "ESM-100 file.py fix" file.py` command `file.py` **IS NOT** a part of commit message, but (*not mandatory*) PATH parameter, which, if used for commit in WC with a more than 1 modification, defines **which changes will be in this commit**, leaving unmentioned object for later processing